# retrieve last modified filename from nested directories

Tags: c#, file, file-management

I have a root directory and inside that further directories are there. These directories contains various Html and ncx files. I have to get the name of the file that has been last modified. 
I am using this code

```
    string filePath = @"~\FolderName\";  
string completeFilePath = Server.MapPath(filePath);  
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(completeFilePath);  
var fileName = (from f in directory.GetFiles()  
orderby f.LastWriteTime descending  
select f).First();  
lblDisplayFileName.Text=fileName.ToString();
```

But it is only searching files that are placed only in root directory. It is not searching files that are present further in directories of root directory. I don't know how to get last modified filename of the files that are present further in nested directories. I have to display the name of file that has been last modified from all of the files irrespective of present in any directory.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation of [`DirectoryInfo.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cyf24ss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

[**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cyf24ss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Returns a file list **from the current directory**.

You have to use the [overload that takes a `SearchOption`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
directory.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Comment: var dir = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
           
            for (int i = 0; i < dir.Count(); i++)
            {
              
                var dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(dir.ToString());
                var fileName = (from f in dir1.GetFiles()
                                orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
                                select f).First();
                MessageBox.Show(fileName.ToString());
            }
I have updated my code like this but still i am not getting my desired result.

Comment: can you please explain what changes should i do and where ?

Comment: @user: change your code `... from f in directory.GetFiles() ...` to `... from f in directory.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories) ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try the overload of GetFiles which takes 2 parameters

from f in directory.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

SearchOption specifies whether the search operation should include only the current directory or all subdirectories.